# Identifying when ALL displays have been modified in the Views UI

Tags: views

A question about the visual identification of displays that have been changed within the views admin UI.

If you modify a single display a * gets added to the display's tab. However, if you select 'All Displays' the display on which you are working gets the * added to the tab but other subsequent displays which have been modified do not.

This can lead to problems if a user inadvertantly selects 'All Displays', as they will be making changes to displays that they are unaware of.

Does anyone know if there is a patch or module which exists to alter this functionality such that if a change is made to all displays that it adds the * to all display tabs, not just the tab for the display from which the change was made?

Thanks,
Pablo